# Monk Dragon's tail vs. Duergar Stand Your Ground - Does SYG Apply?

Tags: dnd-4e, monk, racial-traits, powers, duergar

The move element of Dragon's Tail is:

- Move : Swap places with target

Duergar have Stand your Ground:

- Stand Your Ground: When an effect forces you to move — through a
  pull, a push, or a slide — you can move 1 square less than the effect
  specifies. This means an effect that normally pulls, pushes, or
  slides a target 1 square does not force you to move unless you want
  to.

I contend that the 'swap' is not a pull, push or slide and therefore SYG does not apply as a defense against it.

Does it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Yes, you can resist being swapped

Although the power merely says "swap places", the Rules Compendium clearly details what a "swap" means:

> Slide: Sliding a target can move it in any direction. Sometimes a creature can **swap places** with a target. Doing so is a special kind of slide; the creature slides the target into its space and then shifts so that its space includes at least 1 square that the target just left.

Thus, a swap *IS* a slide, and the Dwarf or Duergar can reduce the slide by 1, making themselves unswappable.